# how do I fix CharField attribute error in django?

Tags: python, django, attributes, syntax-error

I am a beginner and this might seem very trivial to most. I am getting an the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Dev\hoss\myfirst\app_one\models.py", line 3, in 
>       class Question(models.Model):   File "C:\Dev\hoss\myfirst\app_one\models.py", line 5, in Question
>       textone = models.CharField(max_lenght=128)   File "C:\Dev\hoss\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 1037, in **init**
>       super().**init**(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'

for the following code and cant fix it any body can help:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):

    textone =       models.CharField(max_lenght=128)
    pub_date =      models.DateTimeField()


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. `textone =models.CharField(max_lenght=128)` it should be `textone =models.CharField(max_length=128)` and `text = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)`, it should be `text = models.CharField(max_length=200)`